# Адаптеры Wi-Fi не найдены

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, драйвер

Итак. Установил на ноутбук Lenovo 590 основной ОС Ubuntu 18.04.3, все было окей, пока не обнаружил, что к домашнему wifi подключиться не могу. Полез в интернет, там пишут про 2 проблемы: что-то не то при установке ОС, либо драйвера сетевухи. Первый пункт сделал, переустановил, проблема не ушла. Начал решать второй вариант, радостный подключил кабель в ноут, надеясь скачать драйвера через терминал и опа, кабель тоже не виден, интернета по кабелю так же нет. Есть вариант с установкой драйверов с флешки, но тут возникает другой вопрос: какие, откуда и как. Очень нуждаюсь в вашей помощи

Comment: Раскатайте вначале дистрибутив со свежим ядром, посмотрите, заведётся или нет. Например, Arch Linux.

Comment: Для начала покажите вывод команды `ip addr` и вывод команды `lspci -nn`

Comment: И что у вас в `/etc/apt/sources.list`  обычно дрйвера в ветке non-free